# How do I turn off Tab and New Line markers in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, aptana, coldfusionbuilder

I am using Adobe's ColdFusion Builder, an Eclipse-based IDE built on top of Aptana.

All of a sudden, I am getting a type of whitespace marker showing in my Eclipse Editor. I must have accidentally hit a key combination.

Here is a screen dump.

[image: screen dump of markers I am seeing]

I have already tried "General > Editors > Text Editors > Show whitespace characters" and it is not this.  **I already have show whitespace characters turned off**.  If I turn it on, then the Whitespace Characters display over the top of what I am already seeing.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how this can be turned off?  Most annoying.

Many Thanks

Comment: I added a starting sentence to clarify this isn't just a base Eclipse. (CFB being Aptana-based may have relevance to where settings are stored - in that there _might_ be another CFB-specific set of these settings elsewhere in Preferences.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this several times by accidentally hitting some keystrokes.

If you go to Windows/Preferences/General/Keys you will see all the keyboard shortcuts you have.

Mine is set to Control + . 
 (that's a period by the way) I had to place my cursor inside the document and do it a couple of times to make it work because there is also a keyboard shortcut for Control +

On a Mac it is Cmd +.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 14):

It's under Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors

Just uncheck 'Show Whitespace Characters':

[image]

Comment: Hi Yalestar, thanks for your reply.  As per my post, I already have "show Whitespace Characters" turned off.  If I turn it on it shows another marker set over the top of this one.  I have pasted a screen dump of my current settings.  Any other suggestions?  I have tried everything but without luck.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Restarting Eclipse? If that didn't work, you might try this http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka11640.html which explains which file to delete to force eclipse to revert to use default settings.

Comment: Reset a customized perspective

After you have modified a perspective, you can restore it to its original layout.

In ColdFusion Builder, select Window > Preferences.
In the Preferences dialog box, you see a tree-view structure on the left side.
In the tree-view structure, select General > Perspectives.
Under Available Perspectives, select the modified perspective that you want to reset.
Click Reset, and then click OK. You can also use this to add a new perspective which may get rid of the white space markers.

Comment: Thanks Craig.. this seems to be the only option, but worked!  Thanks!

Comment: An update on this one.. I found that Cmd+. (command + period) removes the formatting.