# Unusual syntax in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: As you can see clearly in the pic i am getting this unusual symbols when i am typing my code ,i don't know what i did in my settings ?i tried reset perspective and restore to default and everything but not able to get rid of this ,please help here.]

As you can see clearly in the pic i am getting this unusual symbols when i am typing my code ,i don't know what i did in my settings ?i tried reset perspective and restore to default and everything but not able to get rid of this ,please help here

Comment: Those symbols are whitespace. Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992739/how-to-get-rid-of-eclipse-white-space-characters

Comment: I haven't seen them in Eclipse before, only in Microsoft Word, but it symbolises the newline character.

Comment: i want to get rid of these characeters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330620/eclipse-i-turned-on-hidden-characters-now-i-cant-turn-off

Comment: thanx to all,its gone now

Comment: If your problem has been fixed, please consider accepting one of the answers below as they are both correct. This will make it easier for others with the same issue to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13003022/3399526

> It's under Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors
>
> Just uncheck 'Show Whitespace Characters':

Answer (score 2):

Window->Preferences

General->Editors->Text Editors. Uncheck "Show whitespace characters" and it should solve your problem